# Selecionar apenas 1 registro com a categoria igual e da hidden nos outros

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho que listar uns thumbs da mesma categoria só que quero que apareça 1 para o usuário e os outros fiquem como hidden no código. Estou vendo com **GROUP BY categoria** só que se faço isso e dou `while()` ele lista só um por categoria e os outros que teriam que ficar como hidden não ficam.

```
<?php

$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projetos");

$i = 0;

while($e = mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){

echo $e["categoria"];

if($i > 0){

echo "<div style='display:none;'>".$e["categoria"]."</div>";
$i = 0;
}

$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Não entendi o problema, pode postar parte do código?

Comment: @PapaCharlie Eu tenho um campo chamado "categoria" e nela tem a categoria do registro. Tenho por exemplo 10 registros todos com a mesma categoria. Queria pegar e listar na tela 1 registro e os outros 9 listar também, só que deixar com o style="display:hidden"

Comment: Exclui minha resposta anterior por estar incompleta, não alterei para que os comentários não ficassem sem sentido... Postei uma nova resposta com base no que entendi do deu problema.

Answer (score 1):

O comportamento do `GROUP BY` é esse mesmo, juntar os registros iguais e mostrar apenas 1.
Você deve usar o `ORDER BY` para juntar os iguais e mostrar um depois do outro, no final do while memorizar a categoria para comparar no próximo registro, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$categoria_anterior = NULL;

$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projetos ORDER BY categoria, id");

while($e = mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){
    echo '<div' . ($e['categoria'] == $categoria_anterior ? ' style="display:none;"':'') . '>' .
        $e['categoria'] .
    '</div>';
    $categoria_anterior = $e['categoria'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Executei testes com o exemplo e está rodando conforme você explicou.
Tentei comentar o código o máximo possível de forma simples.

```
$limit = 10;
$counter = 1;
$categoria = null;

while( ... )
{
    // verifica se mudou a categoria, e inicia o contador se for maior que 1
    if( $categoria !== $row['categoria'] and $counter > 1 )
    $counter = 1;

    if( $counter === 1 )
    {
        echo $e['categoria'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div style="display:none;">' . $e['categoria'] . '</div>';

        // reinicia o contador se for maior que o decimo item
        if( $counter === $limit ) $counter = 0;
    }

    // incrementa o contador e grava a categoria atual
    $counter++;
    $categoria = $e['categoria'];
}
```

> Algumas situações para ilustrar o agrupamento

<sub>**• categoria['A'] 10 registros**

» 1º visible e 9 hidden</sub>

<sub>**• categoria['A'] 15 registros**

» 1º visible e 9 hidden + 1 visible e 4 hidden</sub>

<sub>**• categoria['A'] 10 registros | categoria['B'] 5 registros**

» 1º visible e 9 hidden(CAT-A) + 1 visible e 4 hidden(CAT-B)</sub>

<sub>**• categoria['A'] 5 registros | categoria['B'] 10 registros**

» 1º visible e 4 hidden(CAT-A) + 1 visible e 10 hidden(CAT-B)</sub>